# Deploying with tomcat-maven-plugin

Tags: maven, tomcat7, maven-tomcat-plugin

I got 401 error when I was trying to deploy my maven project to tomcat 7 on debian.

```
     org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:redeploy (default-cli) on project ClientPortal: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager
        at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractCatalinaMojo.execute(AbstractCatalinaMojo.java:149)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractWarCatalinaMojo.execute(AbstractWarCatalinaMojo.java:70)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://localhost:8181/manager/text/deploy?path=%2FClientPortal&war=&update=true
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1626)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:604)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.TomcatManager.deployImpl(TomcatManager.java:662)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.TomcatManager.deploy(TomcatManager.java:295)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractDeployWarMojo.deployWar(AbstractDeployWarMojo.java:85)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractDeployMojo.invokeManager(AbstractDeployMojo.java:85)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractCatalinaMojo.execute(AbstractCatalinaMojo.java:141)
        ... 22 more
```

My tomcat is running on port 8181 and here is my pom.xml

```
 <build>
            <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
            <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.2</version>
                            <configuration>
                                    <url>http://localhost:8181/manager/text</url>
                                    <server>Tomcat7</server>
                                    <username>admin</username>
                                    <password>tomcat</password>
                                    <path>/ClientPortal</path>
                            </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.3</version>
                            <configuration>
                                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                            </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>3.1</version>
                            <configuration>
                                    <source>1.7</source>
                                    <target>1.7</target>
                            </configuration>
                    </plugin>
            </plugins>
    </build>
```

tomcat-users.xml

```
<tomcat-users>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<user password="tomcat" roles="manager-script" username="admin"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

I also tried to create a settings.xml in my .m2 directory

```
   <settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <localRepository/>
  <interactiveMode/>
  <usePluginRegistry/>
  <offline/>
  <pluginGroups/>
  <servers>
        <server>
         <id>Tomcat7</id>
         <username>admin</username>
         <password>tomcat</password>
        </server>
  </servers>
  <mirrors/>
  <proxies/>
  <profiles/>
  <activeProfiles/>
</settings>
```

Answer (score 0):

Error 401 is flag for Unauthorized URL.  Please check for valid User/Password.

Change tomcat-users.xml as

```
  <tomcat-users>
   <role rolename="manager-script"/>
     <role rolename="manager"/>
    <role rolename="admin"/> 
   <user password="tomcat" roles="manager-script,manager,admin" username="admin"/>
 </tomcat-users>
```

to try for manager login

Comment: I have made the changes but still no luck.